# Arc GIS Need to define the selected object in a hyperlink

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcmap

I am an ArcGIS 10.1 basic license user.  I have a project where when I select a segment I need 4 images (which are associated with that particular segment) to appear.  I figured out that I could use write a little vbscript and use the hyperlink function to make this happen.  It all works like a champ.

My problem is when I click on hyperlinks all of my segments turn yellow (the color I set the hyperlinks to).  What I need is a way to define the selected hyperlink so I can easily tell which segment the images are coming from.

ANY IDEAS???

Thanks Much for your time.

Comment: So you want to turn only one (selected) segment yellow, not all the segments in the layer -- correct?

Comment: I want to turn the selected hyperlink segment a color different from the non-selected segments.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so far? (At least the portion that's changing the segment color)

Comment: This is the code I use to pull up the 4 associated images.  It works fine.    Function OpenLink ( [ImageLink], [ImageLink2], [ImageLink3], [ImageLink4] )
  Dim path, path2, path3, path4
  Dim objShell
  path = [ImageLink]
  path2 = [ImageLink2]
  path3 = [ImageLink3]
  path4 = [ImageLink4]
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  objShell.ShellExecute path, "", "", "open", 1
  objShell.ShellExecute path2, "", "", "open", 1
  objShell.ShellExecute path3, "", "", "open", 1
  objShell.ShellExecute path4, "", "", "open", 1
End Function